# "cannot be resolved to a type" TOMCAT - JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have built a web application using JSP and Tomcat server. It works just fine on localohost.
I have then deployed it on another server and when trying to run it i get following error messsage.

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 221 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
"SearchFiles" cannot be resolved to a type
```

That happens with every class located in a subfolder.
As I have searched through the internet, that is a common bug, but I haven't found any solution.

I have to mention that the local Tomcat's version is 7, while the remote servers' version is 6, that could be the cause of the problem probably.. The fact is that I do not have the rights to update it.

I have also tried to make some changes in the server.xml and ROOT.xml files of tomcat, but it didn't work as well.

Please provide some help, it's the last thing I need to finish my Thesis!!

Comment: You must have forgot to deploy something. Are your WEB-INF/classes and /lib all in place?

Comment: yes everything is the right place. As i said, the project runs perefectly on localhost. As about the external server, every jsp page that doesn't use those "java classes located in a subfolder" works perfectly! The problem is on those pages that use them.

Comment: I placed again the classes in WEB-INF/classes directory. Now the jasper doesn't throw any exceptions and the website runs.BUT ONLY the html code created py jsp files!! When I am calling the java files, it doesn't seem to recognise them.

Comment: How do you call the Java files?

Comment: What was the solution to this problem?